# Saving Forwarded URL Parameters to MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where customers send bulk SMS, so I forward the SMS request to Aggregator and he delivers the message through Mobile Operators in India.

Now, the issue where I am facing is. Once SMS are delivered, to get real time delivery report, I need to use a script in PHP to receive parameters from aggregator. So I have done a script as example.com/dlr.php and script contains

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$uid = sanitize($_GET['uniqueid']);
$status = sanitize($_GET['status']);
$cause = sanitize($_GET['cause']);

if($uid != "" || $status != "" || $cause != "" ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` .....";
    //execute code...
}
```

So using this, I store that data in my DB and update the records at interval.

My dedicated server crashes when aggregator sends simultaneous request to my URL `example.com/dlr.php?uniqueid=1234332423&status=success&cause=delivered&time=12312432423`, so the said URL comes **multiple times at once**, sometimes thousands times, when my customer sends out messages in 100,000 numbers and all that 100,000 number delivery report are getting forwarded to my script.

So may be due to this, my server crashes and become inaccessible.

What is the best way to handle concurrent connections to this script and store the values to my MySQL DB?

Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: The easiest way (that is, which requires no hardware upgrade and no intensive server optimization) would be to cache the messages on your side and deliver them in bulks your machine can cope with.

Comment: When your aggregator sends them server crashes? Have you monitored the number of connections?

Comment: @sammry Yes it crashes, and as per monitoring, the server crashes when there are reports forwarded more than 20k numbers

Comment: how many php-fpm processes do you have? since you have GET request you can see all requests in access.log of apache or nginx whatever web server you use. analize it - get the proper number. check how many requests are coming in 1 particular second. than try to do some tests to simulate that load. How long does it take to process 1 request? did you ever measure that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with your database - rather than the script itself. I would check the maximum number of connections you are allowing... by default this number is set to `100`. The maximum number of connections you could have is `4,294,967,295`

Check this link for info on how to change it: [MySQL Connection Limit](https://major.io/2007/01/24/increase-mysql-connection-limit/)

Also, can you post some logs of your sever, before, during and after the crash? so that we can better understand whats happening and why...

---

A better method would be to stagger your data import. ie; write your receipts to a temporary text file - then using cron jobs - every X minutes; read the temporary text file and import the first batch of data to your database.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a comment (but its a bit long).

You need to reign in your expectations here. Both your description of the issues and your analysis is wrong.

You will not get a valid answer here because there is huge amount of information needing to be gathered to identify what the problem really is and how to fix it. You should start by gathering proper metrics on memory, CPU, load, concurrent connections, number of webserver processes, query response times....and that is just a *start* on the capacity management. You didn't even think that the operating system this runs on was relevant to your question!

But server crashes should have *nothing* to do with capacity - excess demand should not cause your server to crash. That implies a whole lot of other things could be happening. And to find out what they are you need to go read your logs. If the "crashes" are coincident with high demand then high on the list of things to check would be a dodgy disk controller or a misconfigured webserver + memory overcommit + oomkiller. Both scenarios would leave plenty of evidence in your logs.

You also need to refine your understanding of what is happening when the system goes from its usual state to the state you describe as a "crash" - either that or explain it a lot better.

Quickest fix here is to go buy more server harder, if that doesn't fix it then it'll probably be cheaper to hire a expert than to acquire the skills you need to resolve this.

(if this really is dedicated hardware then even the cheapest x86 box available is capable of handling upwards of 500 concurrent connections and 1000s of transactions per second).